# Print whole tensors in Keras using print_tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using **print_tensor** to see the values of tensors in a custom loss function. However, this only prints the first three values! Like this:

`softmax = [[-0.245408952 -0.0407191925 -0.0813238621]...]`

In Tensorflow you can control this using the summarize parameter in tf.Print (not applicable in my case), but print_tensor for Keras has no such parameters, so how can I change this behaviour?

So far I have tried:

1. Reading the documentation (and, briefly, the code) for print_tensor, but I could not find any parameters
2. Very naively setting numpy to write whole arrays

`import numpy
 numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)`

Comment: Maybe it won't be possible to solve this using Keras yet: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10566